# Excel combobox limit to list

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, combobox, vba

I have a project that involves comboboxes.  There is a record for every hour of the day, each with a combobox for listing a relevant problem code.  If there are multiple problems during any given hour, the user can click a checkbox to add additional rows, including an additional combobox.  I want to make sure that all the comboboxes are limited to the list; I can do that for the existing set of 24 records by changing the style property to Style 2-frmstyledropdownlist instead of the default 0-frmstyledropdowncombo.  But I can't figure out how to do this for the additional comboboxes, which are created by code.

This is the code that is used:

```
    'To add combobox for problems
Set x = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1")
x.Name = cmboxName1
x.Height = Rows(rowOffset).Height
x.Width = Columns("G").Width
x.Left = Columns("G").Left
x.Top = Rows(rowOffset).Top
x.Object.Font.Size = 10
```

There are some For..Next statements to populate the Comboboxes, this all works fine except making them limited to the list.  Anyone have any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code for naming the additional comboboxes:
`HrNum = DataEntry.MultiRowCount(cmBox)
    rowOffset = DataEntry.ComboCount(cmBox) + 3 + 1 'a needed offset
cmboxName1 = cmBox.Name & "DOT" & HrNum`

Comment: In case anyone stumbles across this, the answer was: x.Object.style=2.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

To let the user enter text, that is not limited to the list of the ComboBox:

```
x.style = fmStyleDropDownCombo
```

To limit the user to the list of the ComboBox:

```
x.style = fmStyleDropDownList
```

Note that `fmStyleDropDownCombo` has the value `0` and `fmStyleDropDownList` has the value `2`.